# fill months in a Group By

Tags: sql-server, mysql

so im using this query:

```
SELECT  count(ID) AS Count, enrolMonth FROM Accounts GROUP BY enrolMonth.
```

The problem is i dont have any records in January and March, so obviously, with that query i receive only the count of the existing months.

[image]

The problem is im trying to make a bar graph that need to last if the query change (i mean if a new record in January is created, i want the bar graph to adapt to it).

So what im looking to do is the same query but fill the non-existing months like Jan, Mar and May, and in the count col, to fill it with a 0 or null i dont mind..
For the graphics im using Charts.js

As always, thank you all for the help, or for at least trying to.

Saludos desde Chile sucios qlos

Comment: Well, `sql-server` or `mysql`?

Comment: Also how is it possible you just have a month number? How do you differentiate between right now and last February?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH /* RECURSIVE */ Months AS (
    SELECT 1 month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month + 1 FROM Months WHERE month < 12
    )
SELECT COUNT(Accounts.ID) AS Count, Months.month
FROM Months
LEFT JOIN Accounts ON Months.month = Accounts.enrolMonth
GROUP BY Months.month
```

?

For MySQL 5.x

```
SELECT COUNT(Accounts.ID) AS Count, Months.month
FROM (SELECT 1 month UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
   -- add all intermediate rows
      SELECT 11 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 12 ) Months
LEFT JOIN Accounts ON Months.month = Accounts.enrolMonth
GROUP BY Months.month
```